# Rotation between two circles

Tags: geometry, circles, rotations, collision-detection

I have the following collision detection problem that I am trying to solve. I am more of a programmer than a mathematician so please go easy on me!

I have two circles on a Cartesian plane defined by their centroids $(p_1, p_2)$ and their radii $(r_1, r_2)$. Circle 1 is rotated around the origin $O$. Circle 2 lies in the path of circle 1 as it is rotated around $O$. $p_1$ and $p_2$ do not intersect under this rotation (otherwise the solution I seek would be trivial).

I am trying to determine the rotation, $R$ around $O$ at which circle 1 will 'collide' with circle 2 (see the linked image). I can solve this iteratively (i.e. incrementally rotate circle 1 around the origin of the reference frame and test for intersection between circle 1 and circle 2). However, I would like to know if there is a closed form solution to this problem.

Linked image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nevu15hib1onf4/circ_rot.png?dl=0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Bookkeeping: please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math formatting. 2. Hint: The circles collide when the distance between their centers is the sum of their radii. Using this, you should be able to find the two points where the circles collide for the first time by solving for the intersection of the circle of radius $|p_1|$ centered at the origin with the intersection of the circle of radius $r_1+r_2$ centered at $p_2$. I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: Dear KReiser. Thanks for the tip. Amazingly simple to solve now I think about it! I would have accepted this as an answer if it wasn't in the comments as it came first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). If $\rho_i$ denotes the distance of $p_i$ from the origin, and you want the distance between the centres to be $r_1+r_2$, you need the angle bewteen the lines from the origin to the centres to form an angle $\theta$ that satisfies

$$
(r_1+r_2)^2=\rho_1^2+\rho_2^2-2\rho_1\rho_2\cos\theta\;,
$$

and thus

$$
\theta=\arccos\frac{\rho_1^2+\rho_2^2-(r_1+r_2)^2}{2\rho_1\rho_2}\;.
$$

Then you just need to calculate the angle originally formed by these lines and rotate by the difference of the two angles.

Comment: Thanks for your help joriki

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

First circle has equation

$$ (x-h1)^2 + (y-k1)^2 = r_1^2 \tag1 $$

If you rotate its center through angle $\beta$

$$(x-[h1 \cos \beta-k1 \sin \beta])^2+(y-[h1 \sin \beta + k1\cos \beta ])^2 = r_1^2 \tag2 $$

This circle and the second circle below

$$ (x-h2)^2 + (y-k2)^2 = r_2^2 \tag3 $$

should touch. This is ensured when coordinates x or y are solved for the discriminant of quadratic so formed vanishes for a coincident root situation.

Unknown $\beta $ can be solved for. May be a bit cumbersome.